# How do I implement the decoupling capacitor in this diagram?

Tags: capacitor, decoupling-capacitor

I'm following a tutorial on how to control a stepper motor, and it instructs me to place a capacitor across a 12V DC power supply, as shown at the top of the diagram. I've seen explanations for how this doesn't create a short circuit and ought to work, but when I built the circuit as suggested by the diagram and instructions, the capacitor just popped, which kinda matches my intuition. In my circuit, I used a 12V DC battery as the power supply.

I'm a non-EE student working on a personal project, and I'm struggling to get my head around using capacitors in this way and how to perform the circuit analysis. How is a decoupling capacitor meant to be placed in a circuit like this? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: One data point - the longer lead (from the factory) on electrolytic capacitors is typically the + so the pictorial diagram looks wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you either used a capacitor of the wrong voltage (25V would be appropriate here), or connected it backwards.

Comment: @brhans thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a decoupling capacitor is to present a low impedance to AC voltage riding on a DC voltage. In this case the DC is the 12 V supply, the AC is any noise or transients on the DC supply.

A capacitor will block DC and pass AC, so if you put one across the supply leads it will have no effect on the DC, but it will act like nearly a short circuit for AC depending on the frequency, the lower the frequency the larger the capacitor needs to be. A nanofarad capacitor might be good for RF frequencies, for audio or line frequencies (50/60 Hz) it needs to be microfarads, and these will tend to be polarized, you have to connect them positive to positive, negative to negative.

If your capacitor popped there could be several reasons. It could be rated at too low a voltage, but at 12 V it’s unlikely. It could be a bad capacitor, electrolytics have a shelf life, if it was an old one it could fail. More likely it had the polarity reversed, either by connecting it the wrong way around, or by connecting an AC power adapter instead of a DC adapter (you’re using a battery so it’s not an AC adapter, but I just want to add that for completeness).